# Convert Java If-case to Switch

Tags: java

I need help in converting an If-case into a switch statement and I'm working on enums.

An example of my enum is as below :

```
private enum FruitsType{
Apple("Apple"), Orange("Orange"), Mango("Mango"); }
```

And my method which contains If and Else-if Statements is as follows :

```
private String getFruitsPrefMsg() {
String message = getMessage();
if (message == null) {
message = getOtherMessage(); }

if(FruitsType.Apple.toString()) {
//return something; } 
else if(FruitsType.Orange.toString()) {
// return something; }
else if(FruitsType.Mango.toString()) {
// return something; }      
}
```

Not considering the logic in the code as this is just an example of my code, Can someone please help me to convert this aforementioned if and else-if statements(including the check for null) into a simple switch case, I would need the most simplest code possible using swtich. I want to use switch here as this is the criteria and I have to use switch statement.

Comment: Don't know what exactly you are asking for but here is a sample : enum FruitsType {
  Apple, Orange, Mango;
 }

 private void method() {
  switch (FruitsType.Mango) {
  case Mango:
   //do something
   break;
   //... other cases
  default:
   break;
  }
 }

Comment: possible duplicate of [using enum inside a switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086079/using-enum-inside-a-switch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your conditions, you are not using the obtained message at all.

I would make the enum as follows:

```
private enum FruitsType {
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Mango
}
```

As for the switch block, I would probably do something like:

```
private String getFruitsPrefMsg() {

   String message = getMessage();
   if(message == null)
       message = getOtherMessage();

   try {
      switch(FruitsType.valueOf(message)) {
          case Apple:
              //return something
          case Orange:
              //return something
          case Mango:
              //return something
      }
   } catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        //Message is not in the enum.
        //Handle error
        //You can return something here
   }

   //Or return something here
}
```

I know the try-catch block is pretty ugly, but that's the easiest solution i'm able to think of.

Good luck with that.